# Image not displaying XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I created my own button that has Icon on the side and text on the other but the problem is the image is not displaying. did i miss something here? any help would be appreciated. TIA

This is the XAML of the control.

```
<UserControl x:Name="QButtonControl"
    x:Class="CommonLayout.QButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CommonLayout"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="36"
    d:DesignWidth="145" MinWidth="145" MinHeight="36" Loaded="QButtonControl_Loaded">

    <Grid PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered_1" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited_1" MinWidth="145" MinHeight="36" Background="#FFDCD1D1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="btnLabel" Height="20" Margin="36,8,4,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Text Here" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18.667" Width="105"/>
        <Image x:Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="1,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is code behind the control.

```
public sealed partial class QButton : UserControl
    {
        private ImageSource iconDefault;
        private Brush hoverBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 228, 228, 228));

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return btnLabel.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                btnLabel.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public ImageSource Icon
        {
            get
            {
                return iconDefault;
            }
            set
            {
                iconDefault = value;
                img.Source = value;
            }
        }

        public Brush HoverBrush
        {
            get
            {
                return hoverBrush;
            }
            set
            {
                hoverBrush = value;
            }
        }

        public QButton()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Grid_PointerEntered_1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnLabel.Foreground = HoverBrush;
        }

        private void Grid_PointerExited_1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnLabel.Foreground = Foreground;
        }

        private void QButtonControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            img.Source = iconDefault;       
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use a hard coded file path to the image.
Windows Store apps run in a sandbox, so you will not be able to get to any arbitrary file location when you deploy your app.

Second, you can't use backslashes in Image URI. The backslashes are the technical reason you are setting the error you are getting. But just changing to forward slashes in not the answer.

**Access Image in XAML**

If you add an image to your projects `/Assets` folder, you can use XAML like this to show it in QButton.

```
<local:QButton x:Name='qButton1'
               Icon='/assets/jellyfish.jpg'  />
```

**In Code**

To change the Icon in code.

```
public MainPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

}

private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/shrimp.jpg"));
  var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

  var image = new BitmapImage();

  image.SetSource(fileStream);

  qButton1.Icon = image;
    }
```

If you want  the user to choose the Image from their computer at runtime, look at the File Pickers.

[MSDN file pickers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465182.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to set the `Icon` property?

This worked for me

```
<local:QButton Icon="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg" />
```

This worked as well

```
public QButton()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Uri imageUri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg");
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
    this.Icon = image;
}
```

Comment: the Icon Property has the the type of **ImageSource** so i cannot pass a string to save as URI

Comment: You can from XAML, WPF is magic like that :D I made a test WPF application with your code and tried it, give it a shot!

Comment: WinRT information: Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource' from the text 'E:\Icons\metroicons\black\check.png'. [Line: 13 Position: 168]

Comment: Hmm maybe that's a WinRT thing? I didn't know you were using WinRT and I have no experience with it. It definitely works in a normal WPF application though. Try the C# code

Comment: @Hack,  Windows Store apps are not the same as WPF apps. They are closer to Silverlight than WPF.